# Может ли `JNA` работать с библиотеками, написанными на `C#`?

Tags: java, c#

Может ли JNA работать с библиотеками, написанными на C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Из коробки", что прям так "подсунул .NET-сборку, и сразу же загрузил её в JAVA" - нет, не может.

Вам прийдется либо самостоятельно на С/C++ написать прослойку между Java JNA и .Net IJW, либо использовать одну из готовых(например Javonet или JNBridge).